# Delete 80K images from google drive at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I accidentaly unzipped a folder with 80K images in my main google drive folder **MyDrive**. And now I am trying to delete these files. I found a solution at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62496307/remove-files-on-google-drive-using-google-colab) and I am using the following code:

```
import os
import glob

fileList = glob.glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/*.png')
print("Number of files: ",len(fileList))

for filePath in fileList:
    try:
        os.remove(filePath)
    except:
        print("Error while deleting file : ", filePath)
```

The problem here is that, the mounted drive is only showing and deleting few images at a time (between 1000-1500). I have to manually unmount, restart the runtime and mount again to get the next batch of images to delete. Doing this manually will take a lot of time. Is there a way to delete all of it at once?

Comment: Maybe `del filepath` might be better? I never tried deleting so many files before.

Comment: @OriYarden, problem is that i am not getting all the files in `fileList` variable. Only few.

Comment: oof. Are all those files under the same folder (`'/content/drive/MyDrive/'`)? Maybe the issue is `glob` and you could try iterating through all files and `if file_path.endswith('.png'): del file_path`.

Comment: Yes all the files in MyDrive folder. And i dont think that the issue is glob because even when I manually check the files on left side pane under mounted storage in colab, I do not see any file after deletion. Only after I restart the runtime and mount again, I see a new set of files from the drive.

Comment: according to `google-colaboratory`: " only 77 GB is available to the user"

Comment: @OriYarden, yes but the files are in the drive storage. And it's not the size that is the issue. It's the number of files.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with Colab and Python, according to your description, you wanted to delete these files but you had to remount yourself to get the next batch of files.

So my idea is to make the remount step become automatically.

Here's the code I modified for this job.

```py
from google.colab import drive
import os
import glob
import time

attempts = 0
while(True):
  if attempts == 0:
    drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
  if os.path.isdir("/content/drive"):
    fileList = glob.glob('/content/drive/MyDrive/*.png')
    if len(fileList) > 0:
      attempts = 0
      print("Number of files: ", len(fileList))
      for filePath in fileList:
        try:
          os.remove(filePath)
        except:
          print("Error while deleting file : ", filePath)
    else:
      if attempts < 3:
        print("No files left, retrying in 3 seconds...")
        attempts = attempts + 1
        time.sleep(3)
      else:
        print("No files left, stopping")
        break
```

It's not tested but it should do the remount part automatically (if the restart runtime step is not necessary it might work).

Good luck.

Comment: FYI, [here](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/intl/en-GB/faq.html#drive-timeout) are some FAQs from Colab about Google Drive limitations.

Comment: It sounds like this is a problem with the underlying mydrive syching files so this seems like the best approach to me too. Maybe there should be some sleeps and retries when nothing is found in case things are just slow.

Comment: @tdelaney I ran the code in Colab (without png files in my drive), the `drive.mount` will block the execution, not sure if it's also waiting for the file list or just authorization by me. A test with those files can confirm it (which I don't have), but the idea of adding sleeps and retries can be useful, I've added them to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the bash command, to avoid all complications.

```
!rm -r  **.png
```

This will remove all png files. If you want to see which files are deleting real-time just add -v.

```
!rm -rv  **.png
```

[image]

Comment: If python's glob doesn't find the files, rm won't either.

Comment: @tdelaney I said about simplicity :)

Comment: You said "avoid all complications". But since this won't solve the problem... that counts as a complication doesn't it?

Comment: Yes and yes. Did you notice my comment that rm isn't going to somehow magically find more files than glob? This is likely a file sync issue where OP doesn't see all files on the local hard disk.